# When travelling with a minor, is the US consent form ok to use in India and Singapore also?

Tags: usa, india, international-travel, minors

I am travelling with my friend's 8 year old son from India to Los Angeles with a transit at Singapore. Is it enough if the child is carrying a "Minor Travel Consent Form" in the format specified by the destination country (USA) only, or does he need to possess "Minor Travel Consent Form" for India and Singapore?

Comment: In general it's probably fine, but specific countries may have specific requirements that the specific form does not meet.  In this case, you have to look at India's and Singapore's specific requirements.  You should also look at the airline's requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your journey originates in India, you would want to consult its guidance, as noted by [AirIndia for Minors travelling with passengers other than their natural parents](http://www.airindia.in/minors-travelling-with-passengers-other-than-their-natural-parents.htm):

> The following should be borne in mind when a child / infant is accompanied by other adults and not traveling with their parents.
>
> Minors under the age of 18 may require additional documentation if leaving the country of residence. Kindly contact the nearest Consulate for any further details on the points given below :
>
> - Consent (no objection) letter/affidavit signed by both parents ([draft attached](http://www.airindia.in/Images/pdf/Child_travel_no_objection_letter.pdf))
> - Photocopies of relevant pages of both parents passports
> - The original passport should be shown to the check-in Supervisor, to verify the signature authenticity
> - In cases where one of the parents is deceased, photocopy of the death certificate should be given
> - Signatures of the parents on consent letter should match the signature on the passport
> - In the rare case where the family name of the child does not match the parents', birth certificate of the child should be made available
> - Minors under the age of 18 may require additional documentation if leaving the country of residence

Such thorough documentation should suffice for transit and entry, although you may want to include a statement showing your relationship to the child, if you do not have a guardianship document, and the details of where and to whom you are taking the child.